# How to make a dist reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new using Reactjs, and now I need to deploy my react js app on my **shared hosting**.

I use: `create-react-app myapp`

And to run it on dev with `npm start`.

I've tried many suggestions using `browserify` and `webpack`, but until now still no success.

or maybe there is another way to make a dist bundle for my react app?

maybe like `npm run publish` or something like that?

This is my webpack config :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/ 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            },
            { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-loader?pngScale=2' }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './docs'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[npm run build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment)

> `npm run build` creates a `build` directory with a production build of your app. Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your site is served `index.html`, and requests to static paths like `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` are served with the contents of the `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` file. For more information see the [production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) section.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the create react app, so for creating the production build you have to run the :-
**npm run build** or **yarn build**

The app for production to the **build** folder.

To edit webpack configuration in create react app **npm run eject**.

Running this command copies all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. Commands like npm start and npm run build will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point, you’re on your own.